# SQL SET multiple, same as IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new at SQL.
I want to know is it possible to do a SET for many items, such as

```
SET
@item in ('11', '12', '13', '14')
```

So in the WHERE statement, I can

```
WHERE
item_id = @ item
```

Thank you!

Comment: no, but you could try to exchange their place

Comment: Your question isnt clear. Maybe try to explain it on words because looks like you dont know SQL sintaxis. Seem like trying to set a variable, But without a table? maybe you want one array?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a scalar variable.

You can store multiple values with a Table variable though, so that in your WHERE clause you can:

```
WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM @item)
```

Comment: Ah I understand! THank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use table variable and insert the values:

```
declare @itens table (id int)
insert into @itens (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
```

Then you can use

```
WHERE item_id in (select id from @ item)
```

Comment: Alright,thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Tab is right. Something like this can work too

```
declare  @tab table(FirstName  varchar(100))
insert into @tab   values('John'),('Sarah'),('George')

SELECT * 
FROM @tab
WHERE 'John' in (FirstName)
```

Or as in Tab's example,

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField IN(Select FirstName FROM tab)
```